# Error with combobox binding using caliburn micro

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox, caliburn.micro

Hi i have this combobox:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Orders" Width="150" Grid.Row="0"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Order}" Margin="3" />
```

and this is the code in the viewmodel:

```
class MyFerViewModel : Screen, IMyFerViewModel
    {

        private string[] orders = { "ABC", "CDC", "EFR", "ACER" };

        private string order = "ABC";       

        public string[] Orders { get { return orders; } }

        public string Order
        {
            get { return order; }
            set
            {
                if (value != order)
                {
                    order = value;
                    Reorder();
                }
            }
        }

[..]
```

Why when i can't see the view and appere this error in the bootstrapper?

> "Could not locate any instances of contract ABC."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to Bind the `ItemsSource` to the combobox and further the `SelectedItem`

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Orders" 
          Width="150" Grid.Row="0" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Orders}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Order}"          
          Margin="3" />
```

Hope it helps..